# Ubuntu Server unable to install Elasticsearch Unable to locate package

Tags: apt, package-management, elasticsearch

I am trying to install elasticsearch following the instructions at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html onto a laptop running ubuntu server 18.04.5

```
conor@dev:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

```
conor@dev:~$ lscpu
Architecture:        i686
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               28
Model name:          Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz
Stepping:            2
CPU MHz:             844.956
CPU max MHz:         1600.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            3199.76
L1d cache:           24K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            512K
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm dtherm
```

I have listed the commands I have ran and their outputs below but I'm struggling to work out why it cant find the elasticsearch package.

#### Import Key

```
conor@dev:~$ wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
OK
```

#### Install from APT Repository

```
conor@dev:~$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (1.6.12ubuntu0.1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

```
conor@dev:~$ echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main
```

```
conor@dev:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                         
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                      
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:5 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease                                                                
Reading package lists... Done                                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package elasticsearch
```

Comment: I don't think elasticsearch supports i686 arch.

Comment: When I follow those repository URLs, they return 404 Not Found. The repository seems down (or perhaps permanently closed, no way to tell), That's an Elastic issue, not an Ubuntu issue. Contact Elastic to let them know about the problem.  Undo your work and start over following a different method: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html#install-deb